# Why does `pd.Timedelta` fail with a `numpy.str_` input?

Tags: python, numpy

Code:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
ar = np.array(['00:00:00'])
pd.Timedelta(ar[0])
```

Result:

```
TypeError: Expected unicode, got numpy.str_
```

This is quite counterintuitive to me and seems to go against the duck-typed nature of Python.

Note that the following code outputs as expected.

```
pd.Timedelta('00:00:00')
```

output:

```
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')
```

Comment: How would the `Timedelta` constructor know that `'00:00:00'` and `np.str_('00:00:00')` should behave the same way?

Comment: I would expect a numpy string to behave like a normal string

Comment: `pd.Timedelta` is defined in a `pyd` file, a Windows `.dll`.  So I can't readily examine the underlying code.  But since `pandas` uses `object` dtype for Series that contain strings, I'm not surprised that it does not accept the numpy psuedo-string type.

Comment: Note that `datetime` equivalent does not take a string, only a number. `numpy` has a timedelta, which this function accepts: `pd.Timedelta(np.timedelta64(1))`.  So in a sense the string '00:00:00' is an anomoly, even it works for a regular string.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the TypeError is because the pd.Timedelta() function expects a string as input, not a numpy array with a single string element.

As you've noted, using a string works:

```py
pd.Timedelta('00:00:00')
```

returns

```py
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')
```

Alternatively, you can use the numpy string method .item(), like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ar = np.array(['00:00:00'])
pd.Timedelta(ar.item())
```

This should give you the expected output:

```py
Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')
```

Comment: If you look at the code in the question again, you'll see it only passes a single element of the array not the whole array.

Comment: `ar[0]` produces a `np.str_` object, `item()` produces a `str` object.

Comment: If I try to pass the whole array, I get this message `ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible, not ndarray`